# Elsevier: reference format starting with citation, authors, year.. latex

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, citing

I am having problem changing the format of the references to match the ones of the journal I am submitting to. The journal provides a series of styles but none of them matches what they want.

In the text they would like to have citation `(Name, Year)` as in:

[image]

Then in the references they would like them in alphabetical order starting with the same way you cited it in the text, then authors year etc..

[image]

Has anybody ideas on how to make it?

As of now I use:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Elsevier bibliography styles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% To change the style, put a % in front of the second line of the current style and
%% remove the % from the second line of the style you would like to use.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\newcommand*\mycommand[1]{\texttt{\emph{#1}}}
\newcommand{\fB}{f_\mathrm{B}}
\newcommand{\Trca}{T_\mathrm{RCA}}
\newcommand{\Dh}{D_\mathrm{h}}
\newcommand{\fpeak}{f_\mathrm{peak}}
\newcommand{\degC}{^{\circ}\mathrm{C}}
\newcommand{\red}{\textcolor{red}}
%% Numbered
%\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}

%% Numbered without titles
%\bibliographystyle{model1a-num-names}

%% Harvard
\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{authoryear}

%\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{square,sort,comma,numbers}
%% Vancouver numbered
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}

%% Vancouver name/year
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model4-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% APA style
%\bibliographystyle{model5-names}\biboptions{authoryear}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% AMA style
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model6-num-names}

%% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
%\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

and I cite using:

```
\citep{Cho2007}
```

Comment: Have a look at `natbib` if you use `bibtex`.

Comment: I added what I use.

Comment: Your reputation is now over 15 point so you are now able to upvote helpful answers. Have you considered to upvote my answer now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit here is the combination of `author-year` style and bst file `model1a-num-names.bst`, which is usually used with numbered labels ...

But there is the following workaround:

```
%% Numbered without titles % <==========================================
\bibliographystyle{model1a-num-names}\biboptions{authoryear} % <========
```

So with the following changed mwe

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Engstrom2013a,
abstract = {Control of the global epidemic tuberculosis is severely hampered by the emergence of drug-resistant Mycobacterium tuberculosis strains. Molecular methods offer a more rapid means of characterizing resistant strains than phenotypic drug susceptibility testing. We have developed a molecular method for detection of rifampicin-resistant M. tuberculosis based on padlock probes and magnetic nanobeads. Padlock probes were designed to target the most common mutations associated with rifampicin resistance in M. tuberculosis, i.e. at codons 516, 526 and 531 in the gene rpoB. For detection of the wild type sequence at all three codons simultaneously, a padlock probe and two gap-fill oligonucleotides were used in a novel assay configuration, requiring three ligation events for circularization. The assay also includes a probe for identification of the M. tuberculosis complex. Circularized probes were amplified by rolling circle amplification. Amplification products were coupled to oligonucleotide-conjugated magnetic nanobeads and detected by measuring the frequency-dependent magnetic response of the beads using a portable AC susceptometer.},
author = {Engstr{\"{o}}m, Anna and {Zard{\'{a}}n G{\'{o}}mez de la Torre}, Teresa and Str{\o}mme, Maria and Nilsson, Mats and Herthnek, David},
doi = {10.1371/journal.pone.0062015},
isbn = {1932-6203},
issn = {19326203},
journal = {PLoS ONE},
number = {4},
pages = {e62015},
pmid = {23630621},
title = {{Detection of Rifampicin Resistance in Mycobacterium tuberculosis by Padlock Probes and Magnetic Nanobead-Based Readout}},
volume = {8},
year = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Elsevier bibliography styles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% To change the style, put a % in front of the second line of the current style and
%% remove the % from the second line of the style you would like to use.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\newcommand*\mycommand[1]{\texttt{\emph{#1}}}
\newcommand{\fB}{f_\mathrm{B}}
\newcommand{\Trca}{T_\mathrm{RCA}}
\newcommand{\Dh}{D_\mathrm{h}}
\newcommand{\fpeak}{f_\mathrm{peak}}
\newcommand{\degC}{^{\circ}\mathrm{C}}
\newcommand{\red}{\textcolor{red}}
%% Numbered
%\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}

%% Numbered without titles % <==========================================
\bibliographystyle{model1a-num-names}\biboptions{authoryear} % <========

%% Harvard
%\bibliographystyle{cas-model2-names.bst}\biboptions{authoryear}

%\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{square,sort,comma,numbers}
%% Vancouver numbered
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}

%% Vancouver name/year
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model4-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% APA style
%\bibliographystyle{model5-names}\biboptions{authoryear}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% AMA style
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model6-num-names}

%% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
%\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}
\cite{Engstrom2013a}

\citet{Engstrom2013a}

\citep{Engstrom2013a} % <===============================================

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

you get the wished result (no title!):

[image: resulting pbibliography]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INCOLLECTION{Debreu,
  author       = "Debreu, Gérard and Doe, J. and Doe Dor A.",
  title        = "On the use in economic theory of some central results of mathematical analysis",
  booktitle    = "Advances in mathematical economics", 
  volume       = "1",
  pages        = "1--2",
  publisher    = "Springer, Tokyo",
  year         = "1999",
}
\end{filecontents}
\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{,}{,}
\begin{document}
\citet{Debreu}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

I do not have access to Elsevier `bst` files because I never use Elevier'sites. But `plainnat` should do the trick.

[image]